# Cannot access containing class method from inner class

Tags: java

I am creating a custom linked list that implements Iterable.I am trying to call my containing class method remove method from the iterator's remove method but i am unabble to do so.Its says "The method remove() in the type is not applicable for the arguments (int)"

Here is my code :

```
package collections.customCollections.linkedList;

import java.util.Iterator;

public class LinkedList<T> implements Iterable<T>{

private Link<T> head;
private Link<T> tail;
private int size;

public int getSize() {
    return size;
}

public LinkedList(){
    head = null;
    tail = null;
    size=0;
}

public void addAtEnd(T data){   
    Link<T> newNode = new Link<T>(data); 
    //Insert as first element
    if(head == null){
        head = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
    }
    else{
        newNode.previous = tail;
        tail.next = newNode;
        tail = newNode; 
    }
    size++;
}

public void addAtStart(T data){
    Link<T> newNode = new Link<T>(data);
    if(head == null){
        head = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
    }
    else{
        newNode.next = head;
        head.previous = newNode;
        head=newNode;

    }
    size++;
}

//prints the entire linked list
public void print(){
    Link<T> traversalNode = head;
    if(head == null){
        System.out.println("Empty Linked List");
    }
    else{
        while(traversalNode != null){
            System.out.print(traversalNode.data +"->");
            traversalNode=traversalNode.next;
        }
    }
}

public T remove(int index){
    int i=1;
    Link<T> traversalNode = head;
    while(i<index){
        traversalNode=traversalNode.next;
        i++;
    }

    if(traversalNode.next==null){
        removefromEnd();
    }
    else if(traversalNode.previous==null){
        removeFromStart();
    }
    else{
        traversalNode.previous.next=traversalNode.next;
        traversalNode.next.previous=traversalNode.previous;
        traversalNode.next=null;
        traversalNode.previous=null;

    }
    return traversalNode.data;
}

public T removefromEnd(){
    Link<T> nodeToRemove = tail;
    tail = nodeToRemove.previous;
    tail.next = null;
    size--;

    return nodeToRemove.data;
}

public T removeFromStart(){
    Link<T> nodeToRemove = head;
    head = nodeToRemove.next;
    head.previous = null;
    size--;

    return nodeToRemove.data;
}

public T get(int index)
{   Link<T> returnedNode = head;
int i = 1;
while(i < index){
    returnedNode=returnedNode.next;
    i++;
}
return returnedNode.data;
}

private class Link<T>{
    private T data;
    private Link<T> next = null;
    private Link<T> previous = null;

    public Link(T data){
        this.data = data;
    }
}

@Override
public Iterator<T> iterator() {
    return new Iterator<T>(){
        private int position;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            if(position<getSize()){
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public T next() {
            T data=get(position);
            position++;
            return data;
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() {
            remove(position);
        }

    };
}
}
```

Edits : i get that i can call the method using LinkedList.this.remove(). I am more interested in knowing why is it i can call removefromEnd() directly and cannot call this method directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax for accessing the outer *instance's* method is:

```
@Override
public void remove() {
    LinkedList.this.remove(position);
}
```

The compiler - though - provides a convenient way for methods that are unambiguous. That means, you must use the above syntax because a method with the same name (remove) is declared inside the anonymous class. On the other hand - for example - you can directly call `get` in the `next` method.

Comment: But why am i able to call removefromEnd() of the outer class directly?

Comment: But shouldn't the compiler differentiate the functions based on the type or name of parameters?

Comment: Inside the same class, the compiler does that. Keep in mind, that an anonymous class is still a completely other class.